# Member corrupted by initialization of following member

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, member, memory-corruption

During initialization of my class `CTestController` a member std::vector gets corrupted and I have no idea what causes this behavior.

The situation is as follows:

```
class TestController
{
    // ...   
    CReport m_report;
    CTestInspector m_testInspector;
    // ...
}
```

These members get implicitly instantiated in the constructor of `CTestController`.

```
class CReport : public CGenericReport
{
    // ...
    std::vector<SReportData> m_data;
}
```

and

```
class CGenericReport
{
    // ...
    COLORREF m_bgColor;
    const short m_dmOrient;
    long m_defaultCX;
    long m_defaultCY;
    CWnd m_wnd;
}
```

`m_data` is the last member element of `CReport`. It gets properly initialized with size = capacity = 0.

Nothing fancy with the struct:

```
struct SReportData
{
    CPoint pos;
    std::tstring text;
    int fontType;
    COLORREF color;
};
```

After initialization of `m_data` in `CReport` I save the address of its `_Myend` pointer:
**0x03D84500**
A data breakpoint on that location gets immediately hit in the constructor of `CTestInspector`, when the member `m_testInspector` in `CTestController` is located at (`&m_testInspector`):
**0x03D84502**!
This corrupts the `_Myend` pointer resulting in an erroneous `capacity` (eg. 3014656) in `CReport.m_data`.

**What could be the reason for this corruption?**

Additional information:

- Clean/rebuild does not help
- I'm using MFC and Unicode
- Same problem after upgrading to Visual Studio 2013
- `CGenericReport` belongs to another DLL project as `CReport`, moving it to the same module doesn't help
- `sizeof(SReportData)` = 44
- `std::tstring` is typedefed `std::wstring`

Comment: Show all of your class members, not just the ones you think are important.  When you place items in a vector, it is important to know all of the members and what behavior they may have during copy operations (which is what vector does).

Comment: Have you tried to move (temporary) CGenericReport to the same module as CReport?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie All members are shown. I just left out the methods.

Comment: I would suggest you do what KonstantinL stated previously -- move the CGenericReport in the same module as CReport and see what happens.  I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if everything works in that scenario.

Comment: I would be surprised because I have tons of classes that inherit from other modules.

Comment: @Auwald - I wouldn't be surprised, since using classes between DLL's and applications is hazardous unless you know what you're doing.  For one, if your class does any dynamic memory management, then the apps and DLL's must use the same heap manager.  If you built the DLL slightly differently than the apps (i.e. something different in the project build settings), then again, corruption can happen.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `std::tstring`. You must have typedef'd this yourself and added it to the `std` namespace right? Can you show us how you did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different **Member Alignment/Padding** was the problem.

I observed that across two modules the size of `CGenericReport` was different: 136 vs. 134 while including the same header file.

In one case the `m_defaultCX` member was located directly after the 2 byte member `m_dmOrient` while in the other module 2 bytes were included to pad to 8 byte alignment.

Then I checked the alignment settings in the project properties ([/Zp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0.aspx), *Struct Member Alignment* in tab *Code Generation* in *C/C++*). Both were set to *Default* (= 8 byte according to the documentation).
However, when I inserted a

```
#pragma pack(show)
```

into the `CGenericReport` header file, the compiler reported

```
warning C4810: value of pragma pack(show) == 8
...
warning C4810: value of pragma pack(show) == 1
```

for this spot in varying order.

Finally I cotton on to a [#pragma pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) directive

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

being used at the end of another header that overrode the project settings and caused this behavior.
Removing it released me from this trouble. Now the packing alignment of `CGenericReport` is the same for every module.

Comment: Thank you @Peopleware, look at several sites and nothing, but with your answer I found the light at the end of the road. I had a problem similar to yours, and I noticed that in a third-party header they had included `#pragma pack(4)` and the corruption occurred in some of my headers that were linked after the third-party header. The solution was to include a `#pragma pack()` at the end of the third-party header and fixed issue. This last directive re-sets the pack by default established in the compiler.